# Problemas com menu e Iframe

Tags: html

Estou com problema no menu, não fica fixo, e quando o `iframe` da scrool aparece uma borda no fim do `iframe`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>



<style>
body, html {
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}


iframe {
  height: calc(100% - 103px);
  width:100%;
  border:0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;

}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00985F;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #B3E0CF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px  0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  font-family: Roboto, Noto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #007248;
  color: #fff;
}

.topnav a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #007248;
  color: #fff;
}


.navbar{
    background: #00985F;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 56px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
}
.navbar-inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.left{
    float:left;
}
.left a{
    padding: 0 16px;
    line-height: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 16px;
    min-width:30px;
}
.center{
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 2px 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 56px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Roboto, Noto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="http://onfutebol.hospedagemdesites.ws" class="back link icon-only">
                <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path d='M20 11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12 4l-8 8 8 8 1.41-1.41L7.83 13H20v-2z' fill='#ffffff'/></svg>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Municipal de Campo</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="topnav" id="myDIV">
  <a target="Carregar" class="btn active" href="http://onfutebol.hospedagemdesites.ws/xanxere/municipal-de-campo/jogos">JOGOS</a>

  <a target="Carregar" class="btn" href="http://onfutebol.hospedagemdesites.ws/xanxere/municipal-de-campo/classificacao">CLASSIFICAÇÃO</a>
</div>

<iframe name="Carregar" src="http://onfutebol.hospedagemdesites.ws/xanxere/municipal-de-campo/jogos"></iframe>

<script>
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia apontar com imagens o problema também por gentileza?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc tem que colocar `position:sticky` nas `divs navbar` e `topnav`, sendo que a `navbar` fica com `top:0` e a `topnav` com `top:56px`, já que o `height` da `navbar` é `56px`, assim uma não encobre a outra no *scroll*

A barra branca no final da página é pq vc não colocou `display:block` no `iframe`, fazendo isso resolve o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

**OBS:** Seu `iframe` não aparece no *snippet* abaixo pq ele está em `http`, se fosse `https` apareceria no site, é uma questão de segurança, mas no seu ambiente vai ficar certinho!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>



<style>
body, html {
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 140%;
}


iframe {
  height: calc(100% - 103px);
  width:100%;
  border:0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  display: block;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00985F;
  position: sticky;
  top: 56px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #B3E0CF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px  0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  font-family: Roboto, Noto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #007248;
  color: #fff;
}

.topnav a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #007248;
  color: #fff;
}


.navbar{
    background: #00985F;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 56px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}
.navbar-inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.left{
    float:left;
}
.left a{
    padding: 0 16px;
    line-height: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 16px;
    min-width:30px;
}
.center{
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 2px 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 56px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Roboto, Noto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="http://onfutebol.hospedagemdesites.ws" class="back link icon-only">
                <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path d='M20 11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12 4l-8 8 8 8 1.41-1.41L7.83 13H20v-2z' fill='#ffffff'/></svg>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Municipal de Campo</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="topnav" id="myDIV">
  <a target="Carregar" class="btn active" href="http://onfutebol.hospedagemdesites.ws/xanxere/municipal-de-campo/jogos">JOGOS</a>

  <a target="Carregar" class="btn" href="http://onfutebol.hospedagemdesites.ws/xanxere/municipal-de-campo/classificacao">CLASSIFICAÇÃO</a>
</div>

<iframe name="Carregar" src="http://onfutebol.hospedagemdesites.ws/xanxere/municipal-de-campo/jogos"></iframe>

<script>
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show, o menu ficou fixo e o iframe da o scroll por baixo do menu, só que ta o iframe da scroll demais e quando clica na outra tab pra puxar o outro iframe ele abre daonde para o anterior

Comment: @galaxyplay1234 isso é pq eu aumentei a altura do Body para poder ter scroll na janela e vc poder testar é só colocar a altura no Body/HTML em 100% que resolve. Sobre vc puxar outro iFrame e ele ver na posição "errada" ai já é outra pergunta.... Sugiro que se vc considerar que essa resposta responde seu problema marca-la como aceita nesse  ✔️ abaixo das setas do lado da resposta, e abre uma pergunta novo com o código atualizado e explicado o problema de quando vc chama outro iFrame

Comment: Seguinte @hugocsl... Quando eu clico na tab JOGOS para carregar o iframe, ele puxa a pagina dos jogos, aí quando eu dou scroll e paro a pagina pela metade e clico na tab CLASSIFICAÇÃO a pagina vai já com o scroll na metade

Comment: @galaxyplay1234 saquei o problema, faz junto com o script que chama o iFrame novo um evento que scrolla a página para o topo, eu não sou muito bom de JS, mas um document.scrollTop as vezes resolve, como te falei isso é outro pergunta...

Comment: Já consegui arumar... Obrigado, te chamei no face olha lá 

Comment: @galaxyplay1234 legal que resolveu ai, dps eu olho lá, sucesso!

Comment: teria como você me ajudar com uma questão aqui?

Comment: @galaxyplay1234 cara eu manjo muito pouco de iFrame, na verdade quase ninguem mais usa isso pq ele é muito limitado e tem problemas de segurança, basta vc pesquisar aqui no site perguntas sobre iFrame que vc vai ver.... Mas em todo caso abre uma pergunta nova ai, coloca a sua situação e o mínimo de código que de para simular o seu problema, ai eu ou outra pessoa vai poder te ajudar

Comment: não estou conseguindo fazer a pergunta, a sobre php

Comment: teria como conversar com você? Email ou face algo assim?

Comment: @galaxyplay1234 cara eu estou muito agarrado com o trabalho aqui, quase não tenho entrado mais no site. Mas  sei que no FAcebook mesmo tem vários grupos de Dev. Lá com certeza vão te ajudar ;)

Comment: poderia me ajuda com essa questão? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/488727/176259